# Inserting at the begginning of a circular linked list in python

Tags: python, data-structures

Tried implementing a circular linked list in python I'm stuck on the insert() method. Specifically the part of the method where I try to insert an element at the beginning of a list.  As soon as I try to insert at the postion 0, all the other elements somehow disappear lol. Can someone please rectify the error? Here's my code

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class CSL_list:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.head = None

    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            yield node
            node = node.next
            if node == self.tail.next:
                break

    def display(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print("The list is empty")
        else:
            tempNode = self.head
            print("[ ", end="")
            while True:
                print(f"{tempNode.data} -> ", end="")
                tempNode = tempNode.next
                if tempNode.next == self.tail.next:
                     break
            print("]")

    def initialize(self,data):
        first_node = Node(data)
        first_node.next =  first_node
        self.head = first_node
        self.tail = first_node


    def insert(self,data,location):
        new_node = Node(data)
        if self.head == None:
            print("Linked List has not been initialized!")
        else:
            if location == 0:
                new_node.next = self.head
                self.head = new_node
                self.tail.next = self.head

            if location == -1:
               new_node.next = self.tail.next
               self.tail.next = new_node
               self.tail = new_node

            else:
                index = 0
                tempNode = self.head
                while index < (location-1 ):
                    tempNode = tempNode.next
                    index += 1
                new_node.next = tempNode.next
                tempNode.next = new_node
            print("Inserted!")




if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_list = CSL_list()
    test_list.initialize(21)
    test_list.insert(20,-1)
    test_list.insert(22, -1)
    test_list.insert(23, -1)
    test_list.insert(24, -1)
    test_list.insert(989,2)
    test_list.insert(122,0)

    print([node.data for node in test_list])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the `Node` twice because your `else` block executes along with your first `if` block if `location` is 0.

The first `if location == 0` block executes as expected. Then it checks the next if-block, and since it doesn't fit the condition, it executes the `else` block. This is happening because you used 2 disconnected `if` blocks instead of a `elif`.

Try this:

```
            if location == 0:
                new_node.next = self.head
                self.head = new_node
                self.tail.next = self.head
            elif location == -1:   # elif instead of if
                new_node.next = self.tail.next
                self.tail.next = new_node
                self.tail = new_node
            else:
                index = 0
                tempNode = self.head
                while index < (location - 1):
                    tempNode = tempNode.next
                    index += 1
                new_node.next = tempNode.next
                tempNode.next = new_node
```

Comment: *FACEPALM* Thank you so much man! I struggled with this for about 2 hours!